# How to set object position to be center of its mass?

Tags: three.js

[image]

[image]

Right now, when I upload my model, its center(highlighted by transformControls) is not in the model's center of mass. How can I shift it there?

I tried this:

```
(model) => {
    box = new Box3();
    box.expandByObject(model);
    const centerOfBox = new Vector3();
    box.getCenter(centerOfBox);
    const size = new Vector3();
    box.getSize(size);
    const centerOfWorld = new Vector3(0, size.y/2, 0);
    const offset = new Vector3();
    offset.subVectors(centerOfWorld, centerOfBox);

    const scale = model.scale;
    model.translateX(scale.x*offset.x);
    model.translateY(scale.y*offset.y);
    model.translateZ(scale.z*offset.z);
}
```

and also this:

```
(model) => {
    model.traverse(function(child) {
        const rememberPosition = child.getWorldPosition(new Vector3());
        const box = new Box3();
        box.expandByObject(child);

        const centerOfBox = new Vector3();
        box.getCenter(centerOfBox);
        const offset = new Vector3();
        offset.subVectors(rememberPosition, centerOfBox);

        child.traverse(function(ch) {
            if (child instanceof Mesh) {
                ch.geometry.translate(offset.x, offset.y, offset.z);
                ch.translateX(-offset.x);
                ch.translateY(-offset.y);
                ch.translateZ(-offset.z);
            }
        });
    });
    model.position.copy(new Vector3());
}
```

In the latter version, I tried to shift the geometry to be at the object's position and then shift everything (geometry+position) back to the original place (original place = visibly original place).

Comment: Model viewers usually perform this task like so: https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/99b53e3300e25d0d984da46dcfa14a7dfd3ef8de/src/viewer.js#L266-L274. So computing the AABB, retrieve its center point and then use this point to shift the original object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This method gives the same outcome as mine. Visibly, it shifts the object to the center, but its position (transformControls attached to the object) is still **not** at the mass center of the object

Comment: Yeah, this method does not work if you want to change the origin point of your model. Do you mind demonstrating with a live example why translating the geometry has not worked for you?